# Higher-order equivalence of ordinals

Tags: lo.logic, large-cardinals, proof-theory, ordinal-numbers, definability

I wonder which ordinals are second-order equivalent, and similarly for other logical equivalences. Let the signature be fixed and include only <. For concreteness, let us first ask for the first pair of ordinals with the same theory (so seeking what is "indistinguishable" for different expressiveness powers).
Then we have the following:

1. For elementary equivalence, it is easy to see that all ordinals below $\omega^\omega$ are definable, and hence no collision there: $0$ is the smallest ordinal, $1$ is the smallest nonzero ordinal, etc, $\omega$ is the smallest ordinal without a previous ordinal (predicate $\textrm{Succ}(\alpha)=\beta$ is definable), $\omega \cdot 2$ is the next smallest, etc, $\omega^2$ is the smallest limit ordinal without an $\alpha \colon \alpha + \omega = \beta$ (this relation is also definable), and so on. This fails to define $\omega^\omega$, and the corresponding strategy in the Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game is to identify $\alpha \in \omega^\omega2$ with $(\alpha \,\textrm{mod}\, \omega^\omega ) \in \omega^\omega$.

I have found this discussion [Elementary equivalence of ordinals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35971/elementary-equivalence-of-ordinals), which indicates that the smallest ordinal which has the same FO theory as some ordinal below it is $\omega^\omega \cdot 2$ (the theory coincides with that of $\omega^\omega$). If we had access to $+$, the ordinal seems to be $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, since we can define the property "being closed under addition", which is posessed exactly by $\omega^\gamma$. Similarly, if we also had access to $\times$, the ordinal seems to be $\omega^{\omega^{\omega^\omega}}$, and if we had access to ordinal exponentiation, we could formulate the property of being an epsilon-number (but not the relation $\alpha = \varepsilon_\beta$ itself), and hence define all ordinals up to $\zeta_0$.

2. In order of logical strength, the next theory considered in mathematical logic is probably Weak Monadic Second-Order (WMSO), which is encountered particularly if one studies questions related to monadic decidability (such as S2S). "Weak" MSO means MSO with quantifiers over only finite subsets. What is the first collision for this equivalence? I guess it is considerably higher, this theory is usually much stronger.
3. Next, Monadic Second-Order goes. MSO is SO with quantifiers restricted to quantifiers over sets only (and not functions, etc). Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2S. What can be said about its equivalence (or at least, the first collision)? From this point, the considered signatures are equivalent to the simplest non-trivial one: (Succ), since < is definable in terms of successors (the interval of ordinals between the given two is definable).
4. Second-Order equivalence? At this point, I guess the construction will explode. I can see that $+$ becomes definable (or was it before?), as well as $\times$, and probably some weak ordinal collapsing functions. As Wojowy notes, the ordinal here is at least the proof-theoretic ordinal of SO arithmetic (e.g. all recursive ordinals can be defined). Is it much greater than that?
5. Third-Order equivalence

$\dots$

$\omega$. Higher-Order equivalence

The answers should be some ordinals, but of not very large cardinality, due to the following argument: the set of all possible false/true assignments to all the (countably many) valid sentences of a logical theory has cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1$, the continuum, and so the first collision is not later than there. I suspect, however, that the ordinals I have described are all large countable ordinals, probably they have all arisen in proof theory before, as many large countable ordinals. But I cannot prove the countability.

Also, along with that line of questions about **first collision**, a second line of intriguing questions is: what is the **exact upper-bound of all definable ordinals**? For example, $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, is definable in SO due to its property of being the first ordinal of uncountable cofinality, as well as the first Aleph fixed point, as well as some much larger cardinals.

Comment: With full second order arithmetic, this is going to be larger than the length of any second-order-definable well-order $\prec$ of $\omega$, as you can postulate existence of an order isomorphism between $\prec$ and the whole ordinal. This in particular includes all recursive ordinals.

Comment: Edited, thanks! The ordinals appear to be huge starting from SO, indeed. Not sure how mathematical logic handles such ordinals, though.. I guess such things are discussed more in the context of in-some-way-corresponding large cardinals, something about indescribable cardinals is probably near

Comment: If $\kappa$ is [1-extendible](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Extendible), so if there is $j\colon V_{\kappa+1}\to V_{j(\kappa)+1}$, then $\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)$ are second-order equivalent.

Comment: Seems useful: [Second-Order Characterizable Cardinals and Ordinals](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20016843).

Comment: Hanun Jeon and Mohammad Golshani, thank you very much for the references! I find them very interesting)